# Cucumber: How to implement feature directory specific support/hooks.rb functionality?

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber

We're using Cucumber as our test harness

We have a folder structure like this:

```
- automation
    - api
        - api1.feature
        - api2.feature
    - gui
        - gui1.feature
        - gui2.feature
    - step_definitions
        - api_steps.rb
        - gui.steps.rb
    - support
        - hooks.rb
    - cucumber.yml
    - env.rb
    - Gemfile
    - Rakefile
```

I need to have different  actions occurring in my hooks.rb file (or support directory in general) for the api tests vs. the gui tests.  For my api tests, I need to authorize through our restapi and get an auth cookie.  For my gui tests, I need create a selenium browser instance.

I need this to work both when I execute everything by issuing 'cucumber' alone from the 'automation' level of this folder structure AND when I execute a single feature file by doing:

```
    $ cucumber gui/gui1.feature -r features
```

So my questions are regarding how best to do that.

1. Can I/should I create some kind of conditional within my hooks.rb file in the 'Before do' block to perform different before actions based on which directory the feature is executing from?
2. OR Can I/should I create separate support/hooks.rb directories/files within each of the directories 'api' and 'gui'?  (effectively will Cucumber recognize and selectively utilize multiple support directories?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cucumber really doesn't care about directories and are there for organizational purposes only. I would try to avoid any implementation based on file location.

I would implement this with tagged scenarios and hooks.

```
Before('@gui') do
   # create browser/login
end

Before('@api') do
  # create restapi/auth cookie
end

Before ('~@gui','~@api') do
  fail('Silly developer, all scenarios must have an @api or @gui tag!')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run `cucumber --help` and look in particular at the `-r` option you will find there are alternative approach you can use. One of these is to run seperate instances of cucumber with different included files. The best way to configure this is with profiles via cucumber.yml.

You can easily set up a gui profile to include hooks/gui.rb and an api profile to include hooks/api

If you need to get even more seperation another approach would be to run cucumber from each of your subfolder e.g. automation/api automation/gui, and create a support/hooks structure inside those folders.